# How can i draw circle in JFrame without overriding paint(...) or paintComponent(...)

Tags: java, swing, awt, drawing

I want to draw circle using a method that I create but I get a nullPointerException

```
public class GenealogyTreeGUI extends JFrame {
JFrame frame;
Graphics2D g2;

public GenealogyTreeGUI(){
    frame = new JFrame("Genealoy Tree");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    panel.setVisible(true);

}
```

this is my method

```
 public void drawPerson(int x, int y, Person p1){
    System.out.println("----------------------DrawPerson---------------------------------");
    this.g2.drawOval(x, y, frame.getWidth()/12 , frame.getHeight()/12 );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

1. Create a BufferedImage of the size desired
2. Get its Graphics object via `createGraphics()` (for a Graphics2D object) or `getGraphics()` (for a Graphics object)
3. Draw with the above graphics object, and then `.dispose()` it
4. Create an ImageIcon using the above image via `new ImageIcon(myImage)`
5. Display the icon in a JLabel via `.setIcon(myIcon)`

done

[image]

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SomeDrawingFoo extends JPanel {
    private static final int IMG_W = 400;
    private static final int IMG_H = IMG_W;
    private static final Color COLOR_1 = Color.RED;
    private static final Color COLOR_2 = Color.BLUE;
    private static final float DELTA = 40f;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public SomeDrawingFoo() {

        // create image and draw with it
        BufferedImage myImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_W, IMG_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);       
        Graphics2D g2 = myImage.createGraphics();
        Paint gradPaint = new GradientPaint(0, 0, COLOR_1, DELTA, DELTA, COLOR_2, true);
        g2.setPaint(gradPaint);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.fillOval(10, 10, IMG_W - 20, IMG_H - 20);        
        g2.dispose();

        // put image into Icon and then into JLabel
        Icon myIcon = new ImageIcon(myImage);
        label.setIcon(myIcon);
        add(label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new SomeDrawingFoo());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

---

Notes:

- You could also call `.getGraphics()` on your JPanel or JFrame, but the object obtained would not be stable or long-lasting, and this will lead to images that disappear or that cause a NullPointerException. I most definitely do ***NOT*** recommend this
- Usually the *easiest* way to do your graphics is the way that you stated you wished not doing -- draw within a JPanel's `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.